Cant link .cshtml.css file inside of .cshtml in my .NET Application
I have a View Page here: /Views/example/test.cshtml
In the same directory i have /Views/example/test.cshtml.css
Why is the css file not properly linked inside the view?
I even tried using a head tag at the beginning of the view like that:
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.cshtml.css" />
</head>

I tried every possible href path to get the css file. I thought a .cshtml.css file is supposed to be in the same place as the related view page and that it is automatically linked into the view page.

"I thought a .cshtml.css file is supposed to be in the same place as the related view page" The browser uses the page's URL to figure out what path to use when resolving relative URLs for resources like images, CSS and JavaScript files.

I found a solution.
You insert the following into the _Layout.cshtml:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/<project-name>.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

After inserting this line, all the Views which are inserted into the Layout automatically link the css files which are inside of the same directory. One thing it didnt fix: The Layout itself (_Layout.cshtml) is not using its corresponding css file (_Layout.cshtml.css). All the views which are inserted into the Layout automatically link their corresponding css file with the name "<view-name>.cshtml.css".

Static files or any files including .cshtml are not accessible(as public URL) from public locations unless overriding defaults. CSHTML files are handled by the controller and processed & output returns by the same controller/action.
The recommended location for any static files is the "wwwroot" folder.
Example:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" asp-append-version="true" />

